# Find the set of points where equality holds.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $|z|=R,R>1,m\geq 1, n\geq 0$.

a) Prove that $\displaystyle \Bigg|\frac{z^n}{z^m-1}\Bigg|\leq \frac{R^n}{R^m-1}$.

b) Find the set of points where equality holds.

My Try:

I did part a) which is easy. For part b) if equality holds, then $|z^m-1|=R^m-1$. But after that I was stuck. Can somebody help me?

Comment: If you draw a sketch, that would probably help. What is the set $\{ z^m : \lvert z\rvert = R\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both sides are positive, squaring both sides does not change the sense of the inequality.
$$ \lvert z^m-1 \rvert^2 = (z^m-1)(\bar{z}^m-1) = (z\bar{z})^m - (z^m+\bar{z}^m)+1 = R^{2m} -2\Re(z^m)+1 $$
You need this to be equal to $R^{2m}-2R^m+1$, and so you need $\Re(z^m)=R^m$. Since by the triangle inequality $ \lvert \Re(z^m) \rvert \leqslant R^m$, the only time this can be true is if $z^m$ is both real and positive, i.e. $z/R$ is an $m$th root of unity.

Comment: Though you are not squaring it, you are getting the square of the magnitude by multiplying by the conjugate.

Comment: Since both sides are real numbers I really am squaring it. Then I use the relationship $\lvert w \rvert^2= w\bar{w}$.

Answer (score 0):

For part (b) let $z=R e^{i t}$ with $t$ real.Then $$|z^m-1|=|R^m-1|$$ $$\text{iff }  |R^m e^{i m t}-1|=|R^m-1|$$ $$\text{iff }|R^m e^{i m t}-1|^2=|R^m-1|^2$$ $$\text{iff }( R^{2m}-2 R^m \cos m t +1)=(R^{2m}-2 R^m + 1)$$ $$\text{iff } \cos m t=1$$ $$ \text {iff } z^m=R^m$$ $$\text {iff } z=R e^{2\pi i k/m} \text {  for  some integer } k. $$That is,iff $z/R$ is an $m^{\text {th}}$ root of $1$.